# Regex replace, email address from inside email body

Tags: php, regex, email

I have (many) emails which contain addresses like < asd@somewhere.co > inside the body.

I wish to remove the < and > from the email body, but only where there is and @ inside (there are HTML tags in the body too, which must stay).

I can match the address with this regex:

```
^<.[^@]+.@.[^@]+.>$
```

, But how do I replace this with just the address and no < or > ?

Comment: Well, strings are character arrays...

Comment: Are there spaces or did you simply use those to set the angle brackets clearly apart from the email? That is, does the email address look like this: `< asd@somewhere.co >` or like this: `<asd@somewhere.co>`? If the latter, it should be as simple as searching for the `@` sign between two angle brackets set off by word boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search the address you'll want to use something like this:

```
(?:<)([^>]*@[^>]*)(?:>)
```

[Please see Regex 101 here.](https://regex101.com/r/wK1tA7/1) I'm using non-capturing groups for the angle brackets so only what is between them will actually be captured (and I'm not using a particularly good regex for emails, but that should be easy enough to adjust).

You should be able to use the above with `preg_replace_all()` and the `$1` backreference.

Comment: there is no such thing as `preg_replace_all()`

Answer (score 4):

This should do it...

```
<?php
$string = '< asd@somewhere.co >';
echo preg_replace('~<\s*(.*?@.*?)\s*>~', '$1', $string);
?>
```

Search for 'greater than', optional leading whitespace, every character until the first @, then every character until the first 'less than', with optional trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

> I have (many) emails which contain addresses like < asd@somewhere.co >
>   inside the body.
>
> I wish to remove the < and > from the email body, but only where there
>   is and @ inside (there are HTML tags in the body too, which must
>   stay).

Simple. The concept is known as slicing.

```
$email = '<asd@somewhere.co>';


if( strpos( $email, '@' ) ) {

    $new_email = substr( $email, 1, strlen($email)-2 );
    echo $new_email;
}
```

Outputs: `asd@somewhere.co`